# WebView from NDK in android

Tags: android, c++, webview

Is there a way to open a `WebView` from android **ndk**?
We are able to call a java method from jni c++ file and we are able to open a webview but we need to open a webview directly from android ndk without java interference.

Comment: You do realize that `WebView` itself is written in Java, right?

Comment: Did you find a solution, would it be possible to share it here.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access Java UI from NDK code. The NDK's got basic functionality to draw stuff on the screen, suitable for writing games, but that's it.

If you want to use WebView you're going to have to embed it inside a Java UI and then call out to it via JNI. I can't really comment further without more details about what it is you're trying to do, but the usual use cases are:

- game wants to launch a URL: game calls out to Java via JNI and the Java side launches it as an intent.
- game wants to view some HTML in a custom UI: game calls out to Java via JNI and the Java side launches an Activity with a WebView in it.

There are also plenty of ways to cheat, e.g. having a custom activity with no titlebar and a transparent background with a WebView on it appear *on top of* your NativeActivity. It all depends what you want to do, but it's all going to involve JNI.

Comment: I am interested in the last "cheating" example you gave (custom full screen webview overly on a NativeActivity using JNI for communication/function calls). Do you know of any resources I can see to get an idea of how to pull that off?